# Limit Select Option value to Maximum Value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to limit the `select` element that contains product quantity for product size.

When user selects a size (e.g. 16) I want to set `$(orderqty)` maximum quantity to be selected as 1. Rest of the options can be disabled.

My HTML code:

```
<select  name="qty" id="orderqty">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
  <option>5</option>
  <option>6</option>
  <option>7</option>
  <option>8</option>
  <option>9</option>
  <option>10</option>
</select>

<ul class="productinfoul">
  <li>
    <div class="size " title="Size : 16" id="17.99" data-stock="1">16</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="size " title="Size : 18" id="17.99" data-stock="1">18</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="size " title="Size : 20" id="17.99" data-stock="1">20</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="size " title="Size : 22/24" id="17.99" data-stock="2">22/24</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="size " title="Size : 26/28" id="17.99" data-stock="2">26/28</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="size " title="Size : 30/32" id="17.99" data-stock="2">30/32</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="size " title="Size : 34/36" id="17.99" data-stock="1">34/36</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

jQuery code:

```
$('.size').click(function(e) {
  maxval = $(this).attr('data-stock');
  var selected  = $('#orderqty option:selected').text()
    if(maxval < selected){
      alert("You can only select maximum of "+maxval+" for this product"); 
      $("#orderqty").val(maxval).change();
    }
});
```

However this only works if the user selects the quantity first then the product size.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be what you are looking for.

It will only allow the user to select a number from the `select` if its equal or less than the value from `data-stock`

```js
$('.size').click(function(e) {
  var maxval = $(this).attr('data-stock');
  $("#orderqty option").each(function(i, x) {
    if (parseInt($(x).text()) > maxval) {
      $(x).prop("disabled", true)
    } else {
      $(x).prop("disabled", false)
    }
  })

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="qty" id="orderqty">
<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
<option>3</option>
<option>4</option>
<option>5</option>
<option>6</option>
<option>7</option>
<option>8</option>
<option>9</option>
<option>10</option>
</select>

<ul class="productinfoul">
  <li>
    <div class="size " title="Size : 16" id="17.99" data-stock="1">16</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="size " title="Size : 18" id="17.99" data-stock="1">18</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="size " title="Size : 20" id="17.99" data-stock="1">20</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="size " title="Size : 22/24" id="17.99" data-stock="2">22/24</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="size " title="Size : 26/28" id="17.99" data-stock="2">26/28</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="size " title="Size : 30/32" id="17.99" data-stock="2">30/32</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="size " title="Size : 34/36" id="17.99" data-stock="1">34/36</div>
  </li>

</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can disable irrelevant options, depending on which of the size options was clicked. Initially you can disable all options so that user first needs to click on one of the `size` elements.

```js
$('.size').click(function(e) {
 var maxval = parseInt($(this).attr('data-stock') );
 $("#orderqty option").each(function(){
   var curValue = parseInt( $(this).text() );
   if( curValue <= maxval ){
     $(this).prop("disabled", false);
   }else{
     $(this).prop("disabled", true);
   }
 });//each()
});


//Initially disable all options
 $("#orderqty option").each(function(){
    $(this).prop("disabled", true);
 });//each()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select  name="qty" id="orderqty">
<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
<option>3</option>
<option>4</option>
<option>5</option>
<option>6</option>
<option>7</option>
<option>8</option>
<option>9</option>
<option>10</option>
</select>

<ul class="productinfoul">
<li><div class="size " title="Size : 16" id="17.99" data-stock="1">16</div></li>
<li><div class="size " title="Size : 18" id="17.99" data-stock="1">18</div></li>
<li><div class="size " title="Size : 20" id="17.99" data-stock="1">20</div></li>
<li><div class="size " title="Size : 22/24" id="17.99" data-stock="2">22/24</div></li>
<li><div class="size " title="Size : 26/28" id="17.99" data-stock="2">26/28</div></li>
<li><div class="size " title="Size : 30/32" id="17.99" data-stock="2">30/32</div></li>
<li><div class="size " title="Size : 34/36" id="17.99" data-stock="5">34/36</div></li>

            </ul>
```